# D3: Referencing Drop Down Menu Selection

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu, d3.js

I currently have a drop down menu, and want my graph to use data based on the drop down selection. I am a unsure of how to set up my change function (I think that's the solution, please correct me if I am wrong).

The drop down:

```
var menu = d3.select("#projection-menu")
.on("change", change);

menu.selectall("option")
  .data(options)
 .enter().append("option")
  .text(function(d) {return d;});

function change() {
// what do i put here?;
}
```

I then want to change my data based on that selection

```
data = _.where(data, {category: drop-down-selection});
```

I've been looking around and tried something like:

```
function change() {
 var drop-down-selection = d3.select("#projection-menu").node().value;
}
```

but alas that did not work

Thanks! Cheers

Oh, this is all within `d3.csv("test.csv", function(data) {` because i pull the drop down values from the data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I ended up with:

```
d3.csv("test7.csv", function(data1) {

//Dropdown Menu
var a = ["Select one"];

data1.forEach(function(d) {
a.push(d.risk)
});

var arrayUnique = _.uniq(a);

var options = arrayUnique;

var menu = d3.select("#projection-menu")
.on("change", change);

menu.selectAll("option")
  .data(options)
.enter().append("option")
  .text(function(d) { return d;});
```

And then calling to the same csv again after the change function and using `_.where`

```
function change() {
d3.csv("test7.csv", function(data2){
var sel = d3.select("#projection-menu").property("value");
d3.selectAll("div").remove();
var data = _.where(data2, {risk: sel});
```

I initially just tried using `var data = _.where(data1, {risk: sel});` but for some reason that wouldn't work. It would let me load each option once, but would not see a datafile if i tried going back to a previous selection.

Answer (score 0):

if each element in the dropdown has an id you can add an event to each by using

```
document.getElementById("item-id-name").addEventListener("click",function(){
//do some stuff
},false);
```